# Окна в основном окне

Tags: c#, wpf

Работаю в VS2012. Решил реализовать интерфейс окон подобный интерфейсу самой `Visual Studio`. Например, окно свойств в `Visual Studio` можно свернуть, можно прикрепить к любой из сторон основного окна, можно вывести в отдельное окно... Так вот имеется 2 вопроса.

1. Вопрос может некоторым показаться вопросом от неуча, но все таки: Как называется этот элемент? Ведь из за этого я не могу воспользоваться поиском.
2. Как реализовать такие окна?

Comment: Какую технологию вы используете (WPF, WinForms ....)?

Comment: предпочитаю WPF

Comment: В wpf есть TabControl, но его придеться дико кастомизировать для достижения нужного эффекта. Перетаскивание/ смена местами табов - легко сделать. Отделение/отображение во время перетаскивания - намного сложнее. Стоит задуматься, надо ли?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [`AvalonDock`](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @krupennikov: Microsoft обычно открывает внутренние UI-фреймворки, но не сразу (с одной стороны, надо вычистить и причесать, с другой стороны, надо дать другим фирмам развиться и заработать). AvalonDock — хороший проект, попробуйте его.

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо огромное!